# change height based on user resolution with css

Tags: css, media-queries, screen-resolution

I'm trying to override the height of an element based on the users resolution i.e. if its 1024X768 or below i need to increase the height. This must work on all browsers, including ie8. I have the following which does not do anything. Am I using media queries incorrectly? Is this possible to do this with css?

Code:

```css
#element {
position: relative; 
height: 66px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #element {
          height:80px;
             }
}
```

Comment: This should work. Could you send the link to test page (complete html/css)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to go with jquery instead since I need this to work in IE8 as well.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to use javascript for *cross browsing* `$windowWidth = $(window).width();`

otherwise just read this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 0):

There is something else wrong with your code, what you posted here should work. http://codepen.io/watson/pen/IcsEi

Comment: @newbie_86 needs it running for IE8, that's why I suggested JS. `@media` is not supported in IE8 source: caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries